# Angular2: Nested subscribe with second subscribe inside the loop

Tags: angular, http, request, angular2-observables, angular2-http

I am just a week old with Angular2!

There are basically 2 API calls.

1. The first API call get me an array (queryResults) of json objects. (1st Subscribe)
2. Display that array in the view.
3. Loop through the (queryResults) array and pick one particular key: value pair from each array element (queryResults[i].oldLastSeen).
4. Pass that value (oldLastSeen) as a request param to another API which gets me a string (newLastSeen). (2nd Subscribe)
5. Substitute the oldLastSeen with newLastSeen in queryResult

The problem comes in the 5th step due to async nature of Observables. I cannot access `queryResults[i].oldLastSeen` inside inner Subscribe and is basically undefined. Hence the lastSeen doesn't gets updated.

Starting by calling `getLastSeen()`,
Code looks like this:

```
temp: any[];
rows: any[];

getLastSeen() {
    this._someService.getQueryResults(this.query)
      .subscribe(queryResults => {
        this.rows = queryResults;
        this.updateLastSeen(this.rows);
      });
}

private updateLastSeen(rows) {
    this.temp = rows; //temp: any[];
    for(var i=0; i<this.temp.length; i++) {
        if(this.temp[i].id != null || this.temp[i].oldLastSeen != null) {
            //Some operations here
            this._someService.getNewLastSeen(this.temp[i].oldLastSeen)
                .subscribe(
                    newLastSeen => {
                        this.rows[i].oldLastSeen = newLastSeen; //This doesnot happen!
                    },
                    error => alert(error),
                    () => console.log("Finished.")
                );
        }
    }
  }
```

Banging my head since 2 days, came across flatMap, switchMap etc. But highly skeptical about their usage.

**Update: Working Code:**

I followed Bryan's feedback, and made some modifications to his suggested code. Here is what worked for me:

```
this._someService.getQueryResults(this.query)
      .do(qr => {this.rows = qr;})
      .flatMap(queryResults => Observable.from(queryResults))
      .filter(queryItem => queryItem["id"] != null || queryItem["oldLastSeen"] != undefined)
      .do(queryItem => { // did some operations/ manipulations here})
      .mergeMap(queryItem => this._someService.getNewLastSeen(this.queryItem["oldLastSeen]),
           (queryItem, newLastSeen) => [queryItem, newLastSeen])
      .subscribe(([queryItem, newLastSeen]) => {
        queryItem.oldLastSeen = newLastSeen
      });
```

Comment: is it waiting for some input from the user or how is it happening??

Comment: getLastSeen() is called from ngOnInit(). There is no user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you have nested subscribes, you're dealing with an anti pattern that can be improved. I haven't found a compelling case for using one yet. I'm not sure what it means to be skeptical of flatMap or switchMap, but they're incredibly useful operators, especially switchMap. You will not be able to do much beyond rxjs basics without having switchMap in your tool kit.

```
getLastSeen() {
    this._someService.getQueryResults(this.query)
      .do(qr => this.rows = qr;)
      .flatMap(queryResults => Observable.from(queryResults))
      .filter(queryItem => queryItem.id !== null || queryItem.oldLastSeen !== null)
      // you can insert a map or do operator here to accomplish the operations you mention, depending on what they are, or you can possibly just do them inside switchMap
      .switchMap(queryItem => this._someService.getNewLastSeen(queryItem.oldLastSeen),
           (queryItem, newLastSeen) => [queryItem, newLastSeen])
      .subscribe(([queryItem, newLastSeen]) => queryItem.oldLastSeen = newLastSeen);

}
```

taking it piece by piece:

1. you get your query
2. you set the results to the view. functional purists will say doing this here is bad practice as it's using a side effect, but whatever. I'm not a purist.
3. this one is tricky, but you're flattening your results into a stream of observables. You create an observable from your results array, and flatmap emits them one by one, you could have jsut used .mergeAll() here too. This is sort of a more reactive way of looping through the results.
4. filter out the items you're not interested in
5. placeholder line for your "operations", maybe map or do, hard to say without knowing the desired effect. also may just be doable inside switchMap, but points for style and keeping operators succinct.
6. switchMap into the new observable, switchMap will subscribe to the inner observable and emit the result, the key to this is the second argument to switchMap which allow you to combine the item from both the inner and outter observable. here we just put them into an array and emit the array of both values
7. reset the item in the subscription. The only thing fun here is the use of typescript syntax that lets you name the items in your array since you know you're getting an array wiht 2 items.

Comment: Great! This is working but with some modifications. switchMap is cutting down the previous stream and because of that only one queryItem's last seen is getting converted. So I am used mergeMap instead. There were few compilation errors as well but all in all it was a working concept. 
Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it. Yea I'm not surprised that there were some bugs as I just wrote it best I could in the response box.  Always strive to avoid nested subscribes, there is almost always a better way. A best practice is that functions return cold observables and the function caller is responsible for subscribing. This really helps avoid memory leaks as poor subscription management easily creates massive memory leaks.

Comment: Hey bryan, What if I want to do conditional streaming for the second call. I mean I want to call the second API only if certain condition passes. Where can I put that if statement ?

Comment: if you want to do nothing with those, just filter them out like you are already.  If you want to conditionally do an asyn / sync transform , then inside mergeMap (or switchMap) do something like .mergeMap(item => { if (condition) { return asyncTransform(item) } else { return Observable.of(syncTransform(item)) } })  where the async transform returns an observable. If you want all items to process through the stream but perform no op if not condition, then just return Observable.of(item). Totally valid technique. You can also conditionaly apply different async transformations with the same setup